# MVC visual studio and IIS issue

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

For some reason, my visual studio 2013 MVC project is not working anymore.

When I debug in chrome, it will not open chrome and gives me the following error.

It was working fine for over a year.  What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging in another browser?  If yes, did the same message display?

Comment: Yes, I tried firefox, and same problem.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605673/visual-studio-2012-unable-to-attach-the-process-a-debugger-is-already-attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer from the following posts:

[Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)

[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) /App/AngularJS/angular.min.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973749/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-401-unauthorized)

*** setting user to administrator account worked in application pool connect,
*** also changing the Set Application Defaults for all application pools from
ApplicationPoolIdentity --> LocalSystem.